# returning total count of records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-rest

I am using WCF rest service and i want to return total record count just as we have inlinecount in webapi or breeze.

My method in WCF is

```
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GiveMeNamesOfStudents", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<MyDataClass> GiveMeNamesOfStudentsList()
    {
        var returnData = (from myentity in myEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                          select new MyDataClass
                            {
                                Id = myentity.Id,
                                Name = myentity.Name
                            }).Skip(PageSize * PageNo).Take(PageSize).ToList();
        return returnData;
    }
```

How can i return total record count of my actual data together with data?

Comment: You want to return the number of total records found along with the actual paged data?

Comment: What is your question? Count elements in a list? Add a "total record count" property to each outgoing message containing a collection?

Comment: @haim770 yes i want to return count of my actual data

Comment: @Happy, together with the actual data? Or just the count?

Comment: @haim770 together with actual data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to return a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) containing your list and the total count.

You can add other informations like the page count for example but i will keep it simple here.

**First create your generic [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) so you can use it in other methods too.**

```
 public class ListResult<T>
 {
     public List<T> Data { get; set; }
     public int TotalCount { get; set; }
     public int Page{ get; set; }
 }
```

**Now return the object**

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GiveMeNamesOfStudents", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public ListResult<MyDataClass> GiveMeNamesOfStudentsList()
{
    var returnData = (from myentity in myEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                      select new MyDataClass
                        {
                            Id = myentity.Id,
                            Name = myentity.Name
                        }).Skip(PageSize * PageNo).Take(PageSize).ToList();

    return new ListResult<MyDataClass> 
                        { 
                             Data = returnData, 
                             TotalCount = myEntityRepository.Count(), 
                             Page = PageNo 
                        };
}
```

Comment: i am trying .Skip(PageSize * PageNo).Take(PageSize).ToList().count() but its not working

Comment: The method called Count() not count(). Does it work now?

Comment: @dknaack, Your `Count()` will only return the page size.

Comment: Adding count to the end won't work because it will just count the number of items on that page because of the Skip and Take.

Comment: @Happy, It's not working because the method needs to return `List<MyDataClass>`, not `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do query the DB twice; once without `.Skip.Take`, to get the total count, then run the same query again with `.Skip.Take` to get the page of data.

```
    var returnData = (from myentity in myEntityRepository.AsQueryable()
                      select new MyDataClass
                        {
                            Id = myentity.Id,
                            Name = myentity.Name
                        }).Skip(PageSize * PageNo).Take(PageSize).ToList();

    var totalCount = myEntityRepository.myentity.count();
```

---

Another alternative may be to not use EF, and instead just call a stored procedure that could run both queries and return both values in output parameters. This would still run 2 queries, but would only use 1 call frm your app to the DB instead of 2.

Comment: and how do i return this totalCount variable in my return list

Comment: return a container object instead. Something like `class PageResult<T> { public List<T> Data { get; set; }; public int Count { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 2):

Because your method's return type is `List<MyDataClass>`, you can't return anything else. You'll need to introduce a DTO that returns your entities along with the count:

```
public class MyDataClassDTO
{
    public List<MyDataClass> Data { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }   
}
```

And return that.