# How to include total Count in JSON service Side Paging with MVC C# Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I am paging with MVC C# and I have a controller that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetPage(int page, int pageSize)
{
 var dbContext = new DbContext();
 var jobs = dbContext.Jobs.OrderBy(job=>job.Id).skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
 return Json(jobs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

If possible, I would like to return the total count of the jobs without the requirement of a second ajax call. is it possible to somehow tack on to the respone the totalCount of jobs?

Comment: I have not done this in C#, but usually to do this on the server side you would return, for example, an array/list or object with two or more fields: `total` signifying the number of rows of the result, and `data`, the result itself (other fields to include would be `skip` count, for example). Try to look into that.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26779433/991710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
public ActionResult GetPage(int page, int pageSize)
{
    var dbContext = new DbContext();
    int count=(from j in dbContext.Jobs select j).Count();
    var jobs = dbContext.Jobs.OrderBy(job=>job.Id).skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    return Json(new { jobs = jobs, total = count },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a container class to hold both - list of jobs and total count of jobs.  Something like below.

```
public class JobsResult
{
  List<Job> CurrentBatch {get;set;}
  int TotalJobCount {get;set;}
}
```

Set the properties and return this result from your controller method.